# Existing Functions aren't Functions?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm working on a project. My functions are working fine, until all of a sudden I click a button that should run `download()`, but it doesn't. So I open the console, and see this:

```
TypeError: download is not a function
```

And I'm confused. I run `download()` from the console, and it works fine. So I think it might be an issue with `onclick` (my button has `onclick="download()"`), so I use JavaScript to add in the click event instead.

```
$("#download").onclick=download()
```

*Note: `$()` is a custom jQuery-esque function without using the framework itself. It's worked on a lot of other uses at the same time as this problem.*
But that doesn't work either. So I also try using

```
$("#download").addEventListener("click", download)
```

That yet again doesn't work. Both times it said that `$()` was `null`. So I go out on a limb, and try using

```
document.getElementById("download").onclick=download()
```

and the same with `addEventListener()`. But that gives me a very surprising error message:

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

I've repeated all expressions in the console and found that they aren't null. I don't click the button until the page has been loaded very several seconds.

Here is the pertinent code:

```js
function $(el){switch(el[0]){case"#":return document.getElementById(el.substring(1));break;case".":return document.getElementsByClassName(el.substring(1));break;default:return document.getElementsByTagName(el);break;}}

function download() {
 alert("download() executed")
}

// Attempted Scripts:
//$("#download").onclick = download()
//$("#download").addEventListener("click", download)
//document.getElementById("download").onclick = download()
//document.getElementById("download").addEventListener("click", download)
```

```html
<a class = "nav-link nohighlight" id = "download" onclick = "download()">Download</a>
```

It feels like my web browser is just trying to ensure I don't run the function. I've tested this on the latest Edge and Firefox. You can see my full page [here](https://fin444.github.io/profile-builder/).

Comment: Works fine for me, no need for jQuery or a special selector library: https://jsfiddle.net/3rmwbyb4/ (don't use inline event handlers, always attach with Javascript)

Comment: By the way, you can just use `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` - no need for your own `$` selector library.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I pasted your code into mine, and I still got an error saying that `document.getElementById()` is null.

Comment: Can you post your full HTML too, not just the relevant element? You might not be executing the script at the right time.

Comment: @CertainPerformance `document.querySelectorAll()` doesn't let me do things such as read innerHTML and such. Also, give me a bit and I'll upload it.

Comment: @CertainPerformance https://fin444.github.io/profile-builder/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169208/discussion-between-certainperformance-and-fin444).

Comment: just a note: every time you've used something like `.onclick=download()` you're doing it wrong anyway ... because it should be `.onclick=download` - but that's not your issue, it's just something you should know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at where your `script` tag is in your HTML: it's *above* the body. Scripts by default run immediately: when the HTML parser runs across them, it *immediately* executes the script before moving on to parse the rest of the HTML. So, at the time your script runs, none of your elements have been created yet - so, selecting any element will fail.

Either wrap your entire script in a DOMContentLoaded listener function:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // put your whole script here
});
```

Or give your script tag the `defer` attribute, which directs the parser to run it only once the document has been fully parsed:

```
<script src = "index.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: or move your script tag to somewhere in the body, after your `#download` element.